# Why does filtering function in dbpylr turn dataframe into a value list and changes all values to NA in R?

Tags: r, filter, dplyr

I have the following please of code that has data on hospitals throughout the nation. I want to filter for only for the hospitals in TX and put it into a new dataframe called data.

```
outcome <- read.csv("outcome-of-care-measures.csv")
data <- outcome %>% filter(outcome$State == "TX")
```

Seems pretty simple? For some reason though, when I run this piece of code. Instead of being a data frame, the "data" object turns into values and is filled with NA values. What is going on here? I have used the filter option many times.

EDIT: There are NA's in this file. There are 40+ columns. And the value are a "Time-Series".

Comment: you don't need `outcome$` inside the `filter`, do you have any `NA` elements.  Please show a small reproducible example with `dput` i.e. `dput(head(outcome, 20))`

Comment: Its a really long data set - I will edit my original post with it. There are NAs and also the values I'm reference are time series values. I've never encountered that yet in R.

Comment: You can use the `head` of that data in `dput` or can post it in github and then copy the link

Comment: https://github.com/VishaPatel1/Outcomes/blob/main/dput(head(outcomes))

Comment: The data showed have only `"AL"` for `State` variable. Based on that exxample, it s working fine `outcome %>% filter(State == "AL")`

Comment: Nope. All 50 states are listed and any time I select any state, it just does the same thing

Comment: Please check the solution I posted below.  I think the issue is the one I mentioned below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible that the OP didn't load the `dplyr` package

```
library(dplyr)
outcome %>%
     filter(State == "TX")
```

should work

If we don't have the `dplyr`, the `filter` used could be from `stats` and the behavior is very different from the `dplyr::filter`

```
outcome %>%
    stats::filter(outcome$State == "AL")
#Time Series:
#Start = 1 
#End = 20 
#Frequency = 1 
#   [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12] [,13] [,14] [,15] #[,16] [,17] [,18] [,19] [,20]
# 1   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
# 2   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
# 3   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
# ..
```

NOTE: Here, the OP was using `outcome$` and without that it will throw an error

```
outcome %>%
   stats::filter(State == "AL")
```

> Error in stats::filter(., State == "AL") : object 'State' not found